# One RingCentral API call for all extension details

Tags: ringcentral

Sorry, I am new to RingCentral.

I want to know how can all the extension details can be displayed with API?

If an account has 3 extensions, what API can display those extension details calling an API?

We don't want to call multiple APIs to get each extension details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"***As an admin, you can read all extensions by using the [Get Extension List](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Extensions/listExtensions) endpoint. The response contains an array of records with each record contains an extension info***".

check the reference:
ref: https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/8940/retrieve-all-user-details-with-attributes-email-ex.html